# Disable WebSeal "friendly" error pages

Tags: webseal

Our rest services have a built in health check that returns the server status in the form of http status codes, along with a json payload with details (Spring Boot Actuator). If the service is down for any reason, it returns http status code 503 Service Unavailable.
Our rest endpoints are protected by Webseal, which is very helpful and intercepts the 503 and replaces it by a html page:

> #### Third-party server not responding.
>
> The resource you have requested is located on a third-party server. WebSEAL has attempted to send your request to that server, but it is not responding.

This always happen with status code 503, but not with other 5xx status codes.
Does anyone know how to disable this rather useless feature, either globally or per junction?

Webseal error details:

- Code: 0x38cf04d7
- Text: DPWWA1239E

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is two years old, but thought I'd correct the other answer.

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSPREK_8.0.1.2/com.ibm.isamw.doc_8.0.1.2/wrp_config/concept/con_stat_rspons_pages.html

All of the error pages can be customised.  The one you are looking for in the question is the same as the code: 38cf04d7.html.  If you use other languages you may need to remove the other language containers.

If you customise default.html and remove all other HTML pages it will only return that content regardless of error.

Comment: But can you disable the behaviour entirely?

Answer (score 1):

We have a domain dedicated to public api's for partners, and we ran exactly into the same issue. We tried different things without success : configuration, http transformations, deleting the "friendly" errors pages, etc...

We also opened a PMR at IBM explaining the issue and their answer was clear : this behavior cannot be changed on ISAM.

The (workaround) solution we found we to simply stop using ISAM for this particular domain, and using Datapower for url/origin filtering.